# Resume State - Recruiter Distribution

Tags: views, debugging, distributions

I have been using the recruiter distribution for a while and for some reason I remove the ability of the resume state.  I have analyze the problem and the issue is that every time someone register to the website their resume is automatic on visible state. And I need to make sure that the resume remain hidden until the user at least provide their contact information. This is a critical bug on the site because on the resume search show a lot incomplete users.

Anyone can help me to figure out how to enable the resume state functionality ? Or how to troubleshoot this problem. FYI... I updated the recruiter_features module and nothing happen.

I have post this issue on many places and I have not get any response.

https://www.drupal.org/node/2304539 
https://www.drupal.org/node/2311329

Any help will be appreciated.

Views
[image]

Comment: Is the list provided by a view or is it search results from core search, or solr, or...?

Comment: The search is currently provided by a views module. I try to add another filter in the Filter criteria to at least fix the search issue and I couldn't due to the complexity of the views.

In the filter criteria I add that it need to have at least the personal information and did not work.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the views UI for this view so we can get an idea of how it is set up?

Comment: I took an screenshot and upload on the question. Also, I upload it to this URL, http://i.imgur.com/5DA94D2.png

Comment: Do you want incomplete resumés to be able to be published? You might accomplish your goal if you create a requirement that the necessary fields be filled out before the resumé can be published.

Comment: Actually that was the wrong views. Now, upload the correct screenshot http://i.imgur.com/zsgga1I.png . For some reason, this views doesn't allow me to pick a specific field. I did not create this views this views was automate create by the Recruiter Distribution.

Comment: Resume are Profile created by the Profile2 module. By default this distribution will not show any resume on the search until the fill out all the field and that is what is wrong with my site. The website automatic make the profile on the visible state as result user can see it on the search .

Comment: I can tell you some information about this views and maybe we can find a solution.

This views the only thing does its to keep to show only visible a Resume. Unfortunately I don't see any option where I can pick a field. Here is the filter criteria that they provide me http://i.imgur.com/mNGzbCx.png  Hopefully this filter criteria can give you an idea of the option that I have to field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstating and uninstalling the module again fix this issue for me.